# How to get a table to fit its parent container?

Tags: html, css

I have a table that extends beyond its parent container.  How can I get it to fit inside its parent?  I tried following http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html but ran into problems with my columns not lining up.  Someone suggested to change block to row-group but now I can not get the scrollbars to appear even if I hardcode the height.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bwdc78tr/1/

And the HTML

```
<body>

<header id='header'>

    <br>
    <form id='reload' name="Actions" action="Viewer.php" method="post">
        <div id='LookupSection'>
            Whole Number

            <input type="text" id='WholeNumber' name="WholeNumber" title="Enter the whole number here">
            <img id='dropDownButton' src="Images/ComboDropdown.png" title="Click to drop down a partial whole number list based on the current entry" onclick="toggleDropdown()"/>

            <div id='WholeNumberDiv'>
                <table id='wholeNumberDropdown'>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>

</header>

<div id="sidebar">
    <a href="" onclick="window.location.reload();">Clear</a><br>
    <a href="" onclick="gatherImages();">Gather Images</a><br>
</div>

<div id="content">

<Table id="ImageDataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr style="position:relative;display:block">
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:200px;">Whole Nbr</div>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:50px;">Type</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:50px;">Size</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:100px;">Revision</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:100px;">Other Nbr</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:50px;">Sheet Nbr</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:50px;">Of Sheets</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:50px;">Frame Nbr</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:50px;">Of Frames</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:250px;">Doc Title</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:100px;">Volume</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:50px;">Note</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:50px;">Prnt</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:50px;">Obs</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:100px;">Acquire Date</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:150px;">Source</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:100px;">Base Doc</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:100px;">Acc Doc Nbr</th>
                    <th class='ImageDataCell' style="width:100px;">CommonSubDirectory</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="display:block;overflow:auto">

<tr>

<td class="ImageDataCell" width="200px">

    SS1026

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    DD

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    A

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    2

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    10

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    10

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    1

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    1

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="250px">

    JOGGLING OF ALUMINUM ALLOY EXTRUDED

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    89576

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    No

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    No

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    2004-07-15

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="150px">

    DSCR

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    Yes

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    \CDVolumes

</td>

</tr>            
<tr>

<td class="ImageDataCell" width="200px">

    SS1026

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    DD

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    A

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    2

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    10

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    10

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    1

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    1

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="250px">

    JOGGLING OF ALUMINUM ALLOY EXTRUDED

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    89576

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    No

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    No

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    2004-07-15

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="150px">

    DSCR

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    Yes

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    \CDVolumes

</td>

</tr><tr>

<td class="ImageDataCell" width="200px">

    SS1026

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    DD

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    A

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    2

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    10

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    10

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    1

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    1

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="250px">

    JOGGLING OF ALUMINUM ALLOY EXTRUDED

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    89576

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    No

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    No

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    2004-07-15

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="150px">

    DSCR

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    Yes

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    \CDVolumes

</td>

</tr><tr>

<td class="ImageDataCell" width="200px">

    SS1026

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    DD

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    A

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    2

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    10

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    10

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    1

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    1

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="250px">

    JOGGLING OF ALUMINUM ALLOY EXTRUDED

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    89576

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    No

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    No

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    2004-07-15

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="150px">

    DSCR

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    Yes

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    \CDVolumes

</td>

</tr><tr>

<td class="ImageDataCell" width="200px">

    SS1026

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    DD

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    A

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    2

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    10

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    10

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    1

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    1

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="250px">

    JOGGLING OF ALUMINUM ALLOY EXTRUDED

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    89576

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    No

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    No

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    2004-07-15

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="150px">

    DSCR

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    Yes

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    \CDVolumes

</td>

</tr><tr>

<td class="ImageDataCell" width="200px">

    SS1026

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    DD

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    A

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    2

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    10

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    10

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    1

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    1

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="250px">

    JOGGLING OF ALUMINUM ALLOY EXTRUDED

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    89576

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    No

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="50px">

    No

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    2004-07-15

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="150px">

    DSCR

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    Yes

</td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px"></td>
<td class="ImageDataCell" width="100px">

    \CDVolumes

</td>

</tr>            
    </tbody>

    </Table>

</div>

<footer>

    <br>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to find any web pages that explain why sometimes things expand and when they decide not to.  Everything I've seen is simple explanations that don't work in real world situations.  If anyone can suggest good search terms that may help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Table cells expand beyond the size you have specified based on the content.  If a single word is wider than, say 100px, the cell will expand to the width of the wider word, unless you take actions to truncate it.  I would suggest instead you do not try to impose pixel widths for your table cells, and instead let HTML tables render like they normally do.  Widths take care of themselves that way.  As long as you don't change any portion of the table to `display:block` the headers will always align with the body cells.

To create the scrolling table body is not an easy task, but it is definitely possible.  I solved this in the past by creating a normal table (without `display:block` anywhere in the table markup, in fact it will be easier to do this without inline CSS).  Put the original table in a div with `overflow-y:scroll`.

Then, using some script, I created a clone of the header portion of the table and layered it over the top of scrolling DIV. (you'll need to add some right margin to the cloned table in order to account for the width of the vertical scroll bar).  Finally, I put the entire composition inside a DIV with `overflow-x:scroll` so that if the table is too wide for the display, it can scroll horizontally.

This gets around fooling with changing a table's components natural display mode.  It also makes it easier to accommodate browser resize, etc, if you leave the table to manage it's own column sizes, especially if you combine the table and its cloned header with a colgroup to set percentage column widths.  Try not to apply inline CSS to your individual table cells, as it will become a nightmare to manage.

So in concept, the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="tableouter">
  <div class="tableinner">
    <table>
      <colgroup>
        <col style="10%"></col> <--- repeat for each column and adjust width to taste
      </colgroup>
      <thead>
        ...
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        ...
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <table class="headerclone" /> (clone of header portion, including colgroup)
</div>
```

and the basic CSS:

```
.tableouter {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

.headerclone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: 16px;  <-- This accounts for the vertical scroll bar.  I needed to use some script to determine the exact size of the scrollbar for each browser.  Apply this value as inline CSS in your cloning script.
}

.tableinner {
  height: 400px;  <-- this determines the height of the scrolling container.
  overlfow-y: scroll
}
```

Now this glosses over quite a bit of minutiae... to make your cloning script more reliable, you may want to measure the widths of your actual columns and instead apply the explicit pixel widths in the clone's `colgroup`.  Then you might want to put a watcher to resize the clone's columns if the browser is resized, etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for your post Jeff.  Informing me about the cells automatically expanding was very useful.  But that causes a problem.  We have some users here that are not particular computer savy.  If columns move around they can (and will) easily interpret the data wrong and it will be a support nightmare.  That is the reason for the hard coded sizes.  I wanted to create an HTLM page for a couple of reasons; ease of deployment and platform independance.

Comment: If it is impossible to keep the data in the same place (some parts will have data that moves columns around if not set) I will be forced to limit the users to windows machines and give up on the HTML app.  Any comments?